# How do you bind a Datalist that has paging with dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to asp.net and have some clue but not sure how to do this so any help would be great thank you.

I have a Datalist with paging how do the update the datalist from user input via Dropdown list which will bind my datalist and paging?

My private properties

```
private int CurrentPage
    {
        get
        {
            object objPage = ViewState["_CurrentPage"];
            int _CurrentPage = 0;
            if (objPage == null)
            {
                _CurrentPage = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _CurrentPage = (int)objPage;
            }
            return _CurrentPage;
        }
        set { ViewState["_CurrentPage"] = value; }
    }
    private int fistIndex
    {
        get
        {

            int _FirstIndex = 0;
            if (ViewState["_FirstIndex"] == null)
            {
                _FirstIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _FirstIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["_FirstIndex"]);
            }
            return _FirstIndex;
        }
        set { ViewState["_FirstIndex"] = value; }
    }
    private int lastIndex
    {
        get
        {

            int _LastIndex = 0;
            if (ViewState["_LastIndex"] == null)
            {
                _LastIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                _LastIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["_LastIndex"]);
            }
            return _LastIndex;
        }
        set { ViewState["_LastIndex"] = value; }
    }
```

Private methods

```
private void BindItemsList()
    {

        DataTable dataTable = dm.GetDataTable().Tables["product"];// middle tier which pulls data from a database
        _PageDataSource.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
        _PageDataSource.AllowPaging = true;
        _PageDataSource.PageSize = 1;
        _PageDataSource.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
        ViewState["TotalPages"] = _PageDataSource.PageCount;

        this.lblPageInfo.Text = "Page " + (CurrentPage + 1) + " of " + _PageDataSource.PageCount;
        this.lbtnPrevious.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsFirstPage;
        this.lbtnNext.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsLastPage;
        this.lbtnFirst.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsFirstPage;
        this.lbtnLast.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsLastPage;

        this.dlPhones.DataSource = _PageDataSource;
        this.dlPhones.DataBind();
        this.doPaging();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Binding Paging List
    /// </summary>
    private void doPaging()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("PageIndex");
        dt.Columns.Add("PageText");

        fistIndex = CurrentPage - 5;


        if (CurrentPage > 5)
        {
            lastIndex = CurrentPage + 5;
        }
        else
        {
            lastIndex = 10;
        }
        if (lastIndex > Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["TotalPages"]))
        {
            lastIndex = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["TotalPages"]);
            fistIndex = lastIndex - 10;
        }

        if (fistIndex < 0)
        {
            fistIndex = 0;
        }

        for (int i = fistIndex; i < lastIndex; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = i;
            dr[1] = i + 1;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        this.dlPaging.DataSource = dt;
        this.dlPaging.DataBind();
    }
```

Code behind page code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
    }//end of page load
    protected void lbtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CurrentPage += 1;
        this.BindItemsList();

    }
    protected void lbtnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPage -= 1;
        this.BindItemsList();

    }
    protected void dlPaging_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Paging"))
        {
            CurrentPage = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
    }
    protected void dlPaging_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkbtnPage = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtnPaging");
        if (lnkbtnPage.CommandArgument.ToString() == CurrentPage.ToString())
        {
            lnkbtnPage.Enabled = false;
            lnkbtnPage.Style.Add("fone-size", "14px");
            lnkbtnPage.Font.Bold = true;

        }
    }
    protected void lbtnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CurrentPage = (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["TotalPages"]) - 1);
        this.BindItemsList();

    }
    protected void lbtnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CurrentPage = 0;
        this.BindItemsList();


    }
```

asp.net front page

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSearch" runat="server" Text="Search By Phone"></asp:Label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCat" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Nokia</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Samsung</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Motorola</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Sony</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Ericsson</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Sony</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>LG</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Apple</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>HTC</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>BlackBerry</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>HP</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Huawei</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Acer</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Asus</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Dell</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Alcatel</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Vodafone</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>T-Mobile</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Toshiba</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Gigabyte</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Pantech</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>ZTE</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Micromax</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>BLU</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Spice</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Icemobile</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>verykool</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Vertu</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Celkon</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>NIU</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Yezz</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Parla</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Plum</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Sim Card</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DataList ID="dlPhones" runat="server" DataKeyField="PID" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="1" CellPadding="10" CellSpacing="10" >
                    <ItemTemplate>           
                        <asp:Label ID="ProductNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' />   
                        <br />Price:
                        <asp:Label ID="PriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# "$" + Eval("Price") %>'  />
                        <br />

                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass="ImageStyles" ImageUrl='<%# "GetImage.ashx?Id=" + Eval("PID") %>' BackColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderColor="WhiteSmoke" />
                        <br />           
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>                
               <table cellpadding="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnFirst" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnFirst_Click"><img src="images/First.png" height="50px" width="100px" onmouseover="this.src='images/FirstMouseOver.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/First.png';" /></asp:LinkButton>
                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnPrevious" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnPrevious_Click"><img src="images/Previouse.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/PreviouseMouseOver.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/Previouse.png';" /></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="center" valign="middle">
                            <asp:DataList ID="dlPaging" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemCommand="dlPaging_ItemCommand"
                                OnItemDataBound="dlPaging_ItemDataBound">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPaging" Font-Size="X-Large" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PageIndex") %>'
                                        CommandName="Paging" Text='<%# Eval("PageText") %>'></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:DataList>
                        </td>
                        <td align="left">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnNext" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
                                OnClick="lbtnNext_Click"><img src="images/Next.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/NextMouseOver.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/Next.png';" /></asp:LinkButton></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnLast" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lbtnLast_Click"><img src="images/Last.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/LastMouseOver.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/Last.png';" /></asp:LinkButton></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" align="center" style="height: 30px" valign="middle">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPageInfo" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out myself just what to post the solution just in case any one has the same problem.

I'm not sure if this the best way to do it, so please forgive me.

1) Create a `Session["search"] = "First";`

2) Create a method for dropdownlist onselectindexchange

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCat" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="itemSelected">

Code behind method

protected void itemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["search"] = "Second";
        RebindItemList();
    }
```

3) rebind method

```
private void RebindItemList()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = dm.GetSpecifProduct(ddlCat.SelectedItem.Text).Tables["product"];// middle tier method with returns a Dataset or DataTable up to you.
        _PageDataSource.DataSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
        _PageDataSource.AllowPaging = true;
        _PageDataSource.PageSize = 1;
        _PageDataSource.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
        ViewState["TotalPages"] = _PageDataSource.PageCount;

        this.lblPageInfo.Text = "Page " + (CurrentPage + 1) + " of " + _PageDataSource.PageCount;
        this.lbtnPrevious.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsFirstPage;
        this.lbtnNext.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsLastPage;
        this.lbtnFirst.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsFirstPage;
        this.lbtnLast.Enabled = !_PageDataSource.IsLastPage;

        this.dlPhones.DataSource = _PageDataSource;
        this.dlPhones.DataBind();
        this.doPaging();
    }
```

4) logic statement for your paging buttons

```
protected void lbtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CurrentPage += 1;
        string searchCat = (string) Session["search"];
        if (searchCat == "First")
        {
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
        if (searchCat == "Second")
        {
            this.RebindItemList();
        }
    }
    protected void lbtnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentPage -= 1;
        string searchCat = (string)Session["search"];
        if (searchCat == "First")
        {
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
        if (searchCat == "Second")
        {
            this.RebindItemList();
        }

    }
    protected void dlPaging_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Paging"))
        {
            CurrentPage = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            string searchCat = (string)Session["search"];
            if (searchCat == "First")
            {
                this.BindItemsList();
            }
            if (searchCat == "Second")
            {
                this.RebindItemList();
            }
        }
    }
    protected void dlPaging_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkbtnPage = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnkbtnPaging");
        if (lnkbtnPage.CommandArgument.ToString() == CurrentPage.ToString())
        {
            lnkbtnPage.Enabled = false;
            lnkbtnPage.Style.Add("fone-size", "14px");
            lnkbtnPage.Font.Bold = true;

        }
    }
    protected void lbtnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CurrentPage = (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["TotalPages"]) - 1);
        string searchCat = (string)Session["search"];
        if (searchCat == "First")
        {
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
        if (searchCat == "Second")
        {
            this.RebindItemList();
        }

    }
    protected void lbtnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CurrentPage = 0;
        string searchCat = (string)Session["search"];
        if (searchCat == "First")
        {
            this.BindItemsList();
        }
        if (searchCat == "Second")
        {
            this.RebindItemList();
        }


    }
```